# How can I overlap two different SVGs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to overlap two SVGs that were previously one SVG - I just separated the layers so I would have more control.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid container direction="row" justify="center" style={{ height: '90vh', paddingTop: 80, backgroundImage:`url("/media/bg/bg-2.svg")`, backgroundSize:'cover'}}>
                    <Grid item sm={5} style={{ color: 'white', maxWidth: 500, paddingTop: 140 }}>
                        <h1 style={{ fontWeight: 700, color: '#E2A2A5' }}> Lorem Ipsum </h1>

                        <p style={{fontSize: 20}}>
                            Lorem Ipsum
                        </p>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item sm={6}> 
                        <img src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/images/computer.svg')} alt="computer" />
                        <img src={toAbsoluteUrl('/media/images/book.svg')} alt="book" />                        
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6lRs.png)

My aim is to get the two SVGs sitting on top of each other like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip15n.png)

I am aware that it may be a SCSS/CSS problem, but no idea what kind of code would give me the desired results.

All help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Instead of splitting it in two SVGs, might consider using <g>'s to group things into layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a container of those 2 items to `position: relative`

And then set svgs to have `position: absolute`

That way, you can set **z-index**  on svg-s for depth, meaning which one you want to go on top of other.

And for positioning you can use **bottom**, **top**, **left** and **right** to put elements in a place you want to and you would have more control over them.

Edit:

The reason why `position: relative` is important is because elements that are `position: absolute` are positioned from there first parent node that is  `position: relative`.

Comment: Would suggest making only one absolute, so the sizes will be the same

Comment: I will update answer about `position: relative`.

Element who are position absolute are position from there first relative parent.
In this case that would be container